# AutoCAD resbuf migration

Tags: c#, c++, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I have an application which is written in C++ and I have to migrate it to C#. This application is an extension for AutoCAD.

resbuf in C++ AutoCAD API is a linked list, which handles all AutoCAD basic data types. It looks like this

```
struct resbuf {
  struct resbuf * rbnext;
  short restype;
  union ads_u_val resval;
};
```

So, each resbuf contains specific data described by restype member. For example restype with code 410 is layer name. So on C# it looks like this

```
Entity entity; // Get object here
string layer = entity.Layer;
```

In that application resbuf structure is used as a way for working with AutoCAD objects, and wherever I meet resbuf I change it on using object (Line, Polyline, MText and so on) directly.

But now I found usage of resbuf with code 10, and I opened the documentation and found the following

> 10: Primary point. This is the start point of a line or text entity, center of a circle, and so on.

And I don't know the way of migrating it. Because for each object it's a different property. The only idea is something like this.

```
public void ChangePoint(Entity entity, Point3d value)
{
    if (entity is Line)
    {
        // here code for Line
    }
    else if (entity is Circle)
    {
        // here code for Circle
    }
    // And so on
}
```

But I don't like it. May be there is a better way of doing it. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

First resbuf was the ADS version of the AutoCAD API which was a C API. ObjectARX, which is the C++ version of the AutoCAD API, still use resbuf for XData, but not anymore for Entity property access. In ObjectARX (C++) and the AutoCAD .Net API (C#/VB.Net), you access entity property using specific methods and accessors respectively (see examples at the bottom).

Use the [DXF table](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/group_codes_in_numerical_order_dxf_01.htm) to read code in a resbuf linked list.

Second, code DXF 410 is just a string. Someone may use it and store a layer name if he wants, but entity layer is referenced by DXF code 8.

Last DXF code 10, means the first meaningful point for the entity. This can either be the center of a circle, or the 1st point of a line, etc... This is why using the resbuf requires a lot more attention and understand how the underlying AutoCAD database structure is organized, than using accessors.

For Example:

#### ADS (C)

```
ads_name en ;
ads_point pt ;
acedEntSel ("\nSelect an Entity: ", en, pt) ; // was ads_entsel() long time ago
struct resbuf *res =acdbEntGet (en) ;
// ... do something with res parsing the linked list and search for specific codes
// Entity Layer is code 8
// ... Eventually push changes to the entity using acdbEntMod()
```

#### ObjectARX (C++)

```
ads_name en ;
ads_point pt ;
acedEntSel ("\nSelect an Entity: ", en, pt) ; // was ads_entsel() long time ago
AcDbObjectId id ;
acdbGetObjectId (id, en) ;
AcDbObjectPointer<AcDbEntity> pEnt (id, AcDb::kForWrite) ;
AcDbObjectId layerId =pEnt->layerId () ;
// ... do something with pEnt ...
// Eventually set a new layer
pEnt->setLayer (newLayerId, true) ;
```

#### AutoCAD .Net (C#)

```
Document doc =Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument ;
Database db =doc.Database ;
Editor ed =doc.Editor ;

PromptSelectionResult psr =ed.GetSelection () ;
SelectionSet ss =psr.Value ;
SelectedObject so =ss [0] ;

Transaction tr =doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction () ;
Entity ent =tr.GetObject (so.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Entity ;
ObjectId layerId =ent.Layer ;
// ... do something with ent ...
// Eventually set a new layer
ent.Layer =newLayer ;

tr.Commit () ;
// Regen clears highlighting and reflects the new layer
ed.Regen () ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master of C# but know a bit about ARX .
For me it seems like You use some kind of DXF iterator in Your application. 
In C++ You can use acdbEntGet
so in C# You can also use it. See example:

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/accessing-visible-entities-in-a-dynamic-block.html

I suppose In simmilar way You can use corresponding :
acdbEntMake
acdbEntMod
to create, modify entities